# Does "Edge of Tomorrow" relate in any aspect with Scientology?

Tags: analysis, edge-of-tomorrow

Tom Cruise is a famous member of **Scientology** and we also had other Scientology-inspired movies in the past, like "Battlefield Earth". So is there any statement or evidence that **"Edge of Tomorrow"** is another "Scientology approved" vision of **humanity** and the **future**?

Answer (score 11):

There is no relationship between [*Edge of Tomorrow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow_%28film%29) and Scientology other than Tom Cruise's performance.

The film is based on a Japanese novel/manga called [*All You Need Is Kill*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Kill).

Some [sites](http://www.fthismovie.net/2014/06/review-edge-of-tomorrow.html) claim that there is a correlation between Scientological dogma and the plot:

> One more thing: if I didn't know any better, I might read Edge of Tomorrow as Cruise's secret Scientology movie.

But those similarities were already in the manga and weren't added to the script to make it fit their beliefs. Either way, you might find the article interesting.

Plus, according to Wikipedia, Cruise wasn't even the first choice to play the lead, [Brad Pitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow_%28film%29#Development_and_writing) was.

Comment: And last but not least, even if it wasn't an adaptation, people sometimes seem to forget that the lead actor often doesn't have any say in the movie's writing, filming, or production at all, he's just an actor. It's not really Tom Cruise's movie in any way.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, that may be true *often*, but for movies that Tom Cruise is in it's often *not* true.  :)  Cruise has a *lot* of influence on the script writing.  (Christopher McQuarrie is his go-to script "doctor.")  *Edge of Tomorrow* was heavily rewritten based on Cruise's ideas/input, as was *The Mummy* and *Magnolia.*  (These are just examples.)  [Here is one interview as a source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8Q9e6IKA6M); check around the 7 minute mark.  The comment from the director of The Mummy is somewhere else, but shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: Of course, this answer is 100% correct.  :)